# Definition of measurability

Tags: measure-theory

The alternative definition of measurability is:

> A subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a *closed* set $F \subset E$ such that $m^*(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$.

I am asked to show that this is equivalent to the usual definition of measurability:

> A subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an *open* set $O \supset E$ such that $m^*(O \setminus E)<\epsilon$.

My approach is:

If $E$ is measurable, then $E^c$ is measurable. So for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed $F \subset E^c$ such that $m^*(E^c-F)<\epsilon$. Let $O=F^c$

- Since $F$ is closed, $O=F^c$ is open.
- If $F \subset E^c$, then $O=F^c \supset E$.
- Finally, $E^c-F=F^c-(E^c)^c=F^c-E=O-E$, which implies $m^*(O-E)=m^*(E^c-F)<\epsilon$.

Other direction:

Suppose for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open $O \supset E^c$ such that $m^*(O-E)<\epsilon$. This means $E$ is measurable, which in turn means $E^c$ is measurable. So there exists an open $O \supset E^c$ such that $m^*(O-E^c)<\epsilon$. Let $F=O^c$. If $O$ is open, then $F=O^c$ is closed. If $O \supset E^c$, then $F=O^c \subset E$. Finally, $$O-E^c=(E^c)^c-O^c=E-O^c=E-F,$$ which means $m^*(E-F)=m^*(O-E^c)<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is on the right track.

To prove this equivalence, first suppose $E$ is measurable using the closed set definition.

We need to show the open set definition holds.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Since $E$ is measurable, so is $E^{c}$.  But $E^{c}$ measurable means there is some closed $F \subseteq E^{c}$ such that $m(E^{c} - F) < \epsilon$.

But if $F \subseteq E^{c}$, then $E \subseteq F^{c}$, and since $F$ is closed, $F^{c}$ is open.  Finally, $m(E^{c} - F) = m(E^{c} \cap F^{c}) = m(F^{c} - E)$, and so since $m(E^{c} - F) < \epsilon$, we have $m(F^{c} - E) < \epsilon$.  So, given an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we found an open set $O = F^{c}$ containing $E$ such that $m(O - E) < \epsilon$, and this was exactly the definition of measurability using the open sets.

You should try proving the other direction (assume the definition for open sets, and prove it for closed sets), which is very similar, on your own.

Comment: I read only the first part of your answer, up to the sentence "Since $E$ is measurable, so is $E^c$," just so I can treat it as a hint first. Then I updated my question to reflect my latest attempt. I was wondering if my work is correct; I wanted to *really* understand by basically writing your solution in my own words (without looking at your solution prior). If so, then I can take it on from here on my own for the other direction.

Comment: @dragon Your work looks great to me.  Good job!  Now you should prove the other direction (i.e., assume the open definition of measurability and prove the closed definition).

Comment: I have proved the other direction (since it did ask to prove that the two definitions are equivalent, after all), and that proof is indeed very similar to the one for the forward direction. I guess the key idea of this exercise is that, even though we would not reach our destination working with measurability of $E$, we could work with the measurability of $E^c$ instead.

Comment: @dragon You're right.  It's a little tricky at first to realize that you have to work with $E^{c}$, but once you figure that out, the proof comes straight forwardly, as you figured out for yourself.